# What does "object" mean in this context?

Tags: javascript

This is the result of a previous question regarding stepping through json arrays. David, the answerer gave a great answer, but I don't understand what the word "object' is or does in the 'if' statement below. It seems to be a string, but it seems to act like a keyword of some kind. Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

```
function json2txt(obj) {
var txt = '';
    for (var key in obj) {
       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if ("object" == typeof(obj[key])) {
             json2txt(obj[key]);
          } else txt += obj + '\t' + obj[key] + '\r';
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the `json` tag and added `javascript`, as this is a JavaScript question, not a JSON question. :-)

Comment: Could you please link that previous question?

Answer (score 3):

The [`typeof` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) in JavaScript gives you a string telling you whether the operand is an object reference, a number, a primitive string, etc. So that line is checking that `obj[key]` is an object reference.

Here's what `typeof` gives you (from the link above), where the type of the operand is on the left:

- `Undefined`: `"undefined"`
- `Null`: `"object"`
- `Boolean`: `"boolean"`
- `Number`: `"number"`
- `String`: `"string"`
- `Object`: (native and does not implement [[Call]]): `"object"`
- `Object`: (native or host and does implement [[Call]]): `"function"`
- `Object`: (host and does not implement [[Call]]): Implementation-defined except may not be `"undefined"`, `"boolean"`, `"number"`, or `"string"`.

It's probably worth a side note that although `typeof` is frequently written as though it were a function, it is **not** a function, the parentheses are unnecessary. That line could just as well be:

```
if ("object" == typeof obj[key]) {
```

You might also find my blog post on determining the types of things useful: [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)

Comment: T J, thanks so much for that really clear answer. I'll check out your blog, too. Thanks again.